# Using V-model and Value in the Same Element VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use `V-model` and `Value` in the same input. I want to use `Value` for **Initial** Value from `relationship` Laravel and `V-model` for the input.

After Googling for a few minutes, I found out that `V-model` and `Value` cannot use the same input.

[image]

But someone told me I can assign an initial value somewhere in mounted. I did as they said.

```
       created() {

            for (let i in this.form.products) {
                this.form.products[i].quantity = this.form.products[i].pivot.quantity; 
                console.log(this.form.products);
            }
        },
```

But it still didn't help.

**in My Vuejs**

```
    <table>   
       <tr class="tablePurchase--td"  v-for="(item, index) in form.products" :key="index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.code}}</td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    class="table-quantity"
                    v-model="form.products[index].pivot.quantity"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    class="table-quantity"
                    v-model="form.products[index].pivot.unit_price"
                    placeholder="0.00"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Is the `form` property registered in the components data? Or is it just a dynamic property?

Comment: @Jerodev yes, `form`  registered  in data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue reactivity has some caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), one of them is that it is impossible to detect deep changes in an array. Because of this, you should use `Vue.set()` to update deep properties of an object.

So in your case you should do something like this:

```
for (let i in this.form.products) {
    Vue.set(this.form.products[i]), 'quantity', this.form.products[i].pivot.quantity); 
    console.log(this.form.products);
}
```

This will make sure Vue detects the changes and updates the DOM accordingly.

Comment: still, i dont see anything happend in console.log

Comment: You mean you don't see the changes in your console or you don't see anything in your console?

Comment: i mean dont see anything in console.log from `console.log(this.form.products)`

Comment: i also have `this.fetchProduct` in `created`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

```js
new Vue({
 el:"#app",
 data:{
  message:"Hello world!",
  form:{
   products:[
    {id:1, name:'product 1', code:'pcode-1', quantity:6,price:'$300'},
    {id:2, name:'product 2', code:'pcode-2', quantity:8,price:'$800'},
    {id:3, name:'product 3', code:'pcode-3', quantity:9,price:'$700'},
   ]
  }
 },
 methods:{

 }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <table>   
       <tr class="tablePurchase--td"  v-for="(item, index) in form.products" :key="index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.code}}</td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    class="table-quantity"
                    v-model="form.products[index].quantity"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    class="table-quantity"
                    v-model="form.products[index].price"
                    placeholder="0.00"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the the `quantity` value like that but it will not be rendered by vue as it cant detect it. You can check [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). So you can try changing your for loop like below and set `quantity` value with `this.$set`

```
created() {
  // looping on form.products ARRAY
  for (let i = 0; i < this.form.products.length; i++) {
    this.$set(this.form.products[i], 'quantity', this.form.products[i].pivot.quantity) 
    console.log(this.form.products);
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working for me. Can you share your `form` object structure or may be update full vue file if possible.

Comment: take a look at this bro https://gist.github.com/N0SYS73M1SS4F3/37fa687c044952776c305452f4adc906

Comment: I think the issue is that initially your `product` array in `form` property is empty so it can't able to find anything in the products array to loop on in the `created` hook. Hence you have nothing in your console.